# Can not enable data roaming

Tags: roaming

I am abroad and when I enable the *Mobile data* option, i get a warning triangle in the notification area with the text "You have lost data connectivity because you left your home network with data roaming turned off."

Turning *Data roaming* on does not help. Apps claim I have no internet connection.

What is wrong?

One way to understand the message is that data roaming should have been enabled before leaving the home network. Could that be the reason?

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300) with Android version 4.3

Comment: Your provider could have an extra security that ot is disabled by default, even if you have data roaming turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the APN settings were wrong. After correcting them, it works.